# TinyMCE and Angular Can't Disable

Tags: angular, tinymce, angular16

I'm using TinyMCE with Angular 16.
At some points of my application I don't want users to be able to edit the content of a TinyMCE editor.
I'm using the disabled attribute as per the documentation:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/angular-ref/#disabled but it won't work, users can always input into the editor.
Here's how my code looks like:

HTML:

```
<editor
        [init]="editorOptions"
        [disabled]="true"
    >
```

JS:

```
public editorOptions: Object = {
    base_url: '/tinymce', 
    suffix: '.min',             
    toolbar: '',
    menubar: '',
    statusbar: false
};
```

*PS: I tried using the option readonly in the editorOptions with no success.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and tried both ways as well.  I can't get tinymce to be readonly.